# Eclipse can't see my custom layout for listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, layout

In the beginning: I am new in Android and Java programming, but I have a lot of experience with other programming languages like C, C++, Perl, PerlTk, OpenGL, Pascal, Microcontroller programming (C, Assembly), etc... I took a research and I tried a lot of things but nothing helped.

So I want to change the font size and font color in my listview.
I found 2 solutions:

1. Hacking the style. This is working, but if I modify my style than I have to modify all the other elements, what is building from this style. So no, and If I choose this method still I wont be able to modify the listview pressed and not pressed state background colors.
2. Custom layout. I prefer this method, but if I refer the layout, the eclipse says: "cannot be resolve, or is not a field"

My code:

```
public class Btcall extends Activity 
{
  private ListView list;
  final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
  TextView kiirni;
  TextView scanned;
  View view2;
  View view3;
  Button connectbutton;
  private ArrayAdapter<String> founddevices = null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_btcall);
    view2=(View) findViewById(R.id.view2);
    view3=(View) findViewById(R.id.view3);
    connectbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    kiirni=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    scanned=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.scanned);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
  }

  public void irddki(View v) 
  {
    BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = null;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = null;
    bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    founddevices = null;
    if(bluetooth != null)
    {
      String status;
      if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) 
      {
        String mydeviceaddress = bluetooth.getAddress();
        String mydevicename = bluetooth.getName();
        status = mydevicename + " : " + mydeviceaddress;
        Toast.makeText(this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        bluetooth.startDiscovery(); 
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
          {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
            {
              BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

              founddevices.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
          }
        };
        scanned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(470, 270, 0, 0);
        connectbutton.setLayoutParams(lp);
        connectbutton.setText("Scan again");
        kiirni.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        list.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Lightgrayy);
        list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        /*HERE IS THE PROBLEM--->*/
        founddevices = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.mylist);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        list.setAdapter(founddevices);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); 
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
      }
      else
      {
        if (!bluetooth.isEnabled()) 
        {
          Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
          startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public void close(View v) 
  {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
  }
}
```

I wrote a custum layout and I put it in the layouts folder, and it is in the R folder too.

Still the Eclipse can't see it... Maybe I have to import something? I am sure it is a noob Q but I will appreciate the answer.

Comment: Change. Layouts style in right click using eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using just:

```
R.layout.mylist
```

instead of:

```
android.R.layout.mylist
```

Comment: Yes I knew the answer will be something like that... Thanks Reynard!